# connection between moment of normal r.v to gamma function

Tags: normal-distribution, gamma-function, moment-generating-functions

> Problem: $X \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ and $p>1 $. Prove that $E[X^p]=\sqrt{2^p} \times \Gamma\left(\frac{p}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)/\Gamma({1}/{2})$.

I tried calculating the pdf of $X^p$ and then calculating the expectation using $\int xf(x) dx$  and show that it is equal to the right part but haven't managed to get it.

Is there a diffrent approach I should try?

Comment: What does the formula give you for $p=3$ and what _should_ it be giving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) and calculate $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)x^p dx$, where $\phi(x)$ is the probability density of the standard normal.